# Customer and order Item Data on Order Succes page

Tags: magento2, order-success-page

I am trying to getting order,customer and item details on order success page.

```
<?php
 $orderid =$block->getOrderId();
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);

echo "<pre/>";
print_r($order->getData());
?>
```

Is anyone have idea how to get using by directly Object Manager?

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to get order details.

```
protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
){
    $this->order = $order;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getOrderDetails($incrementId)
{
    $orderDetail = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    return $orderDetail;
}
```

Once you get `$orderDetail` object properly, then use following code to get Billing, Shipping and Order Item.

```
<?php $billingAddress = $orderDetail->getBillingAddress()->getData(); ?>
<?php $shippingAddress = $orderDetail->getShippingAddress()->getData(); ?>
<?php $_items = $orderDetail->getAllVisibleItems(); ?>
```

**For Object Manager**

```
<?php 
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId()); 
?>
```